# How to display a hidden checkbox field in a JSP page on the basis of specific value selected from dropdown in Struts 1.3 framework?

Tags: javascript, css, struts-1

I want to create a checkbox in `Struts 1.3 framework` using `Nested Tags`, `Javascript` etc which should only be displayed when a user selects a specific value from a select `dropdown` and the value of `checkbox` should get reset when user chooses other values from `dropdown`.

Comment: what do you mean by hidden ? It is `disabled` or `display:none` ?

Comment: I have used **display:none**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not posted your code I have managed it my own, tried to provide answer

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/39tsgmqf/)

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(function () {
         $("#id-select").change( function(){
          var $this = $(this);
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each( function(){
             if( $(this).val() == $this.val()) {
               
                $(this).parent().siblings().css('display', 'none');
               $(this).parent().css('display', 'block');
                
               $('input[type=checkbox]').css('display', 'none');
               $(this).css('display', 'block');
              }
            })
          });
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='id-select'>
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<div>

<label for="volvo" style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="volvo" value="volvo" style='display:none;'>
volvo</label>

<label for="saab" style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="saab" value="saab" style='display:none;'> saab</label>
  
<label for="opel" style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="opel" value="opel" style='display:none;'> opel</label>
  
<label for="audi" style='display:none;'>
<input type="checkbox" id="audi" value="audi" style='display:none;'>
audi</label>

</div>
```

**UPDATE** using **`JavaScript`**
Hello @Arvind I have changed this to work with **`JavaScript`**,
**May be lots of improvement needed, I do not code in `JavaScript`**

```js
function showCheckBox($this) {
   var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('class-label');
    for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
      cols[i].style.display =    'none';
    }
    var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('class-cb');
    for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
      cols[i].style.display =    'none';
      cols[i].checked = false;
    }
 var array = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var ii = 0; ii < array.length; ii++)
  {
     if(array[ii].type == "checkbox")
     {
        if(array[ii].value == $this.value )
         {
          array[ii].style.display = 'block';
          array[ii].parentElement.style.display = 'block';
         } 
     }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id='id-select' onchange="showCheckBox(this);">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>

<div>

<label for="volvo" class='class-label' style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" class='class-cb' id="volvo" value="volvo" style='display:none;'>volvo
</label>

<label for="saab" class='class-label' style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" class='class-cb' id="saab" value="saab" style='display:none;'> saab
</label>
  
<label for="opel" class='class-label' style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" class='class-cb' id="opel" value="opel" style='display:none;'>opel
</label>
  
<label for="audi" class='class-label' style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" class='class-cb' id="audi" value="audi" style='display:none;'>audi
</label>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Thats a very good approach, But I have to learn Jquery in order to understand and implement the same in my application. Currently, I am just working in pure javascript and Struts 1.3. @ Shantaram

Comment: then you have to placed your code, what you have tried so far, so people who knows `JavaScript`, will be able to help you

Comment: That is so nice of YOU that you tried to help me out by coding even in Javascript. This code will be helpful for my implementation. Thanks again!

Comment: Also I wanted to reset the checkbox once user select other value from dropdown and I am able to achieve using the below code,                              document.getElementById("STYLE_ID").checked = false;

Comment: I did not got you ..`Also I wanted to reset the checkbox once user select other value from dropdown`

Comment: This is just an additional functionality which I wanted to implement. Whenever  user selects some other value in drop down and again selects the same value in drop down, the system reset the value of checkbox.

Comment: Just saw your comment@Shantaram. Here is the code snippet. Please excuse me for not able to share you the code in a way you did which is so easy to understand.

Comment: @arvind if you want to reset all of your  checkboxes, to `display:none;`, then select **`select`** from dropdown, plz ask clearly, still not got you

Comment: it is just a common situation where we should not hold the value of any checkbox if user select other value from select dropdown and  we should reset the checkbox value, so that we will pass only one true value of checkbox to bean class if we include submit button for this operation. Anyway You already have helped me solving out the issue. Thank You once again!!:)

Comment: @Arvind , Now I have added `cols[i].checked = false;` in my code this will first reset all checkboxes  i.e. `It will unckeck all`, now you can send only value which is visible to you...

Comment: As I am new to stackoverflow and have less than 15 reputation, Unable to upvote for the answer. All I can say is that I got the best and quick help from You and it really helped me a lot to develop my code. You rock!!@Shantaram

Comment: @Arvind, surely this won't be best help, but I tried my best... **You can optimize for loops**

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showCheckBox($this) {
   var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('class-label');
    for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
      cols[i].style.display =    'none';
    }
    var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('class-cb');
    for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
      cols[i].style.display =    'none';
    }
 var array = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var ii = 0; ii < array.length; ii++)
  {
     if(array[ii].type == "checkbox")
     {
        if(array[ii].value == $this.value )
         {
          array[ii].style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById("volvo").checked = false;
          array[ii].parentElement.style.display = 'block';
         } 
     }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id='id-select' onchange="showCheckBox(this);">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div>

<label for="volvo" class='class-label' style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" class='class-cb' id="volvo" value="volvo" style='display:none;'>volvo
</label>

<label for="saab" class='class-label' style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" class='class-cb' id="saab" value="saab" style='display:none;'> saab
</label>
  
<label for="opel" class='class-label' style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" class='class-cb' id="opel" value="opel" style='display:none;'>opel
</label>
  
<label for="audi" class='class-label' style='display:none;'>
  <input type="checkbox" class='class-cb' id="audi" value="audi" style='display:none;'>audi
</label>

</div>
```

Comment: just added the below line in your code to reset volvo checkbox                      document.getElementById("volvo").checked = false;                                             I am unable to share my code as my code has lot of dependency on various properties of bean class@Shantaram